# How to add a uiTextfield to a scrollview programmatically using auto layout

Tags: objective-c

I want to add a textfield to a scroll view programmatically using auto layout but when the text field is added it is displayed in the top left corner with the correct size but it has no width (maybe 2 pixels). How can I get the textfield to be constrained to the width of the screen?

The following is in my viewDidLoad method:

```
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [self.scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    self.emailField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [self.emailField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.emailField];

    NSDictionary *views = @{ @"view":self.view, @"scrollView":self.scrollView,  @"textField":self.emailField};

    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:views]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[textField]|"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:views]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[textField(46)]"
    options:0
    metrics:nil
    views:views]];
```

Comment: spuggy, you try to insert self.emailField to your views Dictionary before you initiate it? doesn't it cause an exception?

Comment: If this code runs and does not show the email field, the reason is that you are creating an ambiguous scrollable contentSize for your scrollView. Define width for your content explicity, and then you will see it.

Comment: Mike.R Thanks I've edited my question but that was just a copy paste mistake

Comment: @insane-36 How to define it explicitly for the different size screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the same code that you posted and modified few constraints and added some.

```
 UITextField *emailField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    emailField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    emailField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.emailField = emailField;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

    self.scrollView = scrollView;
    [self.scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    NSDictionary *views = @{ @"view":self.view, @"scrollView":self.scrollView,  @"textField":self.emailField, @"topLayoutGuide": self.topLayoutGuide};

    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views]];

    [self.emailField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.emailField];


    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.emailField
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:10]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.emailField
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:10]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.emailField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.scrollView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-20]];

    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topLayoutGuide][textField(46)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];
```

The important constraints are the width constraint, which relates to the scrollView's bounds. If you do not define width of the subviews in scrollView through autolayout, the scrollView's contentSize is ambiguous and so it cannot determine the width of the content properly. The "|" autolayout format for scrollView, are contentSize edges.

Answer (score 0):

I think insane-36 has the correct answer. 
Just wanted to add additional link with explanation:[Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)